# PHP : How to customing URL

Tags: php, url, request

Maybe this is an easy question.

I have a variable which save the user id in it.

```
$user_id = $_REQUEST['user_id'];
```

and then I have the URL like this :

```
try 
{
    $response = $client->delete('admin/user/**USER ID SHOULD HERE**',[
    'headers' => ['Authorization' => $_SESSION['login']['apiKey']]
    ]);
}
```

I already try to put variable `$user_id` like this `admin/user/$user_id`  in that URL but nothing happens.'

This is the delete method()

```
    public function delete($url = null, array $options = [])
    {
        return $this->send($this->createRequest('DELETE', $url, $options));
    }
```

Am I wrote something wrong ?
Thanks :)

Comment: What does `nothing happens` mean? The url did not have the user id number?

Comment: The url containing the value of user id, but the error message I made said "failed to delete"

Comment: You probably need to show the code for the $client object's `delete()` method to figure out the error.

Comment: You should do some exception handling in a catch

Comment: `$response = $client->delete('admin/user/' . $user_id, [...`

Comment: @Steve : You did it bro :) thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

PHP variables will not be parsed inside of a single quoted string. You should use `"admin/user/$user_id"` if you want the variable's value to be used.

So you could write it like this:

```
$response = $client->delete("admin/user/$user_id",[
```

Or simply by concatenating the string and user id variable using `.`:

```
$response = $client->delete('admin/user/'.$user_id,[
```

Comment: I already tried sir, but the error message still said "failed to delete".  I already try to print the value of $_REQUEST['user_id'] and the value is there.

Comment: well @Monk it looks like my answer is the same as what ended up working for you